# How to draw a head from all angles from imagination?

Tags: drawing, portrait-drawing

I've been drawing portraits for some time, both realistic and stylized.  I can draw from imagination for profile, 3/4 and face-forward views.  But I want to be able to draw from imagination all views: from below, from above, etc.

Currently I have a little plastic head maquette that I use for reference when I do this.  How do I learn to do this from imagination?

Answer (score 1):

I've got some manga art books that are helpful - they give guidelines for drawing heads/bodies at all sorts of angles, whether by using skeleton frameworks, or just drawing freehand.

Also, if you're happy taking a sketchbook around with you, try doing 20-second speed sketches of real people (using pencil, biro, or whatever medium you prefer). Real people don't tend to stand still that long, so you'll have to be quick, but it's a great way of practising natural head positions. (Places like shopping centres or looking out of café windows can be helpful - some places put you below head level, and other put you a storey or two above where people walk).

Answer (score 1):

Having sketch first, and practice.
Head rotation sketches like [This link](http://rebloggy.com/post/drawing-illustration-tutorials-art-reference-how-to-draw-portrait-drawing-figure/138375273741), know about Anatomy and soild drawing, then you try to sketch up your character, then character design.

After design complete, you try to use sketch, then draw your imagination character.
It will be nice, for animation, game concept art, realistic fantasy art and more.
[Examples here](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/564638872002860015/).
If your drawing skill is realistic, character concept art [Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=character%20concept%20art&client=tablet-android-samsung&prmd=ivn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiN8NT-sonWAhULMY8KHdhVD5MQ_AUIECgB).